# Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null on Wikipedia pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

*I am not a JS developper so forgive any horrible code I might have written*

Hi all,

I am working on this chrome extension project, and I am running into a really weird error. The extension is meant to go through a webpage and replace certain words. It seems to work fine on all websites I've tried except for wikipedia. On wikipedia only the words in the first paragraph of the page get replaced and then I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` error thrown.

**Content.js**

```
var nodes = [];
var wordMap = {'color':'colour'}
var regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(wordMap).join("|"),"gi");

if( document.readyState !== 'loading' ) {
    console.log( 'document is already ready, just execute code here' );
    myInitCode();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        console.log( 'document was not ready, place code here' );
        myInitCode();
    });
}

function myInitCode() {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    function(node) {
        var matches = node.textContent.match(regex);

        if(matches) { 
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        } else {
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
        }
    },
    false);

    while(walker.nextNode()) {
        nodes.push(walker.currentNode);
    }

    for(var i = 0; node=nodes[i] ; i++) {
        node.parentNode.innerHTML = node.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(match) {
            return wordMap[match];
        });
    }
}
```

**Manifest.json content script section**

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "*://*/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end" 
    }
]
```

Here is a screenshot of the error occurring:
[image]

And here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

I tried to look around for answers, and I thought the error was happening because the DOM hadn't loaded yet so I added code to address that but the error still happens.
Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: could the unreachable content be in iframes?

Comment: means `parentNode` doesn't exist on the `node` object... just do a check and say `if(node.parentNode)`

Comment: I think you can debug what node has its parentNode as null. `if(!node.parentNode) debugger;`

Comment: @IsaacVidrine yep, well spotted. How silly of me!

Comment: The for loop is wrong. You set i to 0, node to a nodelist item, and then i++.

Comment: @Archer nothing is wrong with the for loop, test it yourself.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine so when does it stop?

Comment: @Archer Im guessing its when `nodes[i]` is undefined... I tested in browser though and it works just like you were saying `i < nodes.length`

Comment: Yes, if the argument is `null` or `undefined` then it counts as being `false` so the loop ends.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Of course it does - that makes perfect sense now I think about it.  Thanks for teaching me a new thing for the day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @IsaacVidrine in the comments to the question the error is caused by `node` not having `parentNode`. To fix it check for existence of `parentNode` in the for loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; node=nodes[i] ; i++) {
        if(node.parentNode){
            node.parentNode.innerHTML = node.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(match) {
                return wordMap[match];
            });
        }
    }
```